# on page load, select data and display on ddl

Tags: asp.net, sql

when pageisload i able to display all the price than store at database but how to control the ddl? the total price is the promotion price, the ddl should select 20% when the page is load.because the selling price discount 20%, but how to do that.
**my database does't store the promotion %/ discount %, how to detect? how to do the converting? by detect the selling price and promotion price, and detect is under wht % of discoun**

[image]

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDis" runat="server" Width="80px" onchange="CalculateCost();">
                    <asp:ListItem>0%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>10%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>15%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>20%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>25%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>30%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>35%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>40%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>45%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>50%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>55%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>60%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>65%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>70%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>75%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>80%</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

while (sqlDataReader1.Read())
                                {
  if (sqlDataReader1["ProductPromotion"].ToString() != null)
                                    {
                                        Literal1.Text = sqlDataReader1["ProductPromotion"].ToString();
                                    }
}
```

---

every product have diff price, how to convert mathematics help

```
    if (sqlDataReader1["ProductPromotion"].ToString() != null)
{
 // var total = selPrice - (selPrice * (parseInt(discount.replace("%", "")) / 100));//formula
  var promotion = sqlDataReader1["ProductPromotion"].ToString();
   var sellPrice = sqlDataReader1["ProductSalesPrice"].ToString();

var total = sellPrice -(sellPrice * promotion)/100); // error
  ddlDis.Items.FindByValue(total);


}

                                }
```

Comment: I understood your Question. Let me know from where the `Total Price` you get. I mean are you getting this price from Database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ddlDis.Items.FindByValue("20%").Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You know the index of the 20% item in the ddl control. You can use the following:

The index of 20% is 3, so you can try:

ddlDis.Items[3].Selected = true;
```

Comment: mathematic help, every product have differenct price